# How to quickly open the current directory from the command prompt? OS - Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, command, command-prompt, explorer

There is a need to quickly open the current directory from the command prompt.
I know that there is a command `explorer`.

But to enter the full path to the directory is very inconvenient.

For example:

```
exoplorer c:\progra~1\nodejs~1\worskp~1\project\module\convert
```

It works. But is that the faster you can open the folder with the mouse ... I think it's not right.

And this command:

```
explorer cd.
```

Opens `My Documents`. Although I am in a different directory.

Whether prompt me please!

Answer (score 75):

You can try:

```
start .
```

or

```
explorer .
```

`.` is a shortcut for current directory.

In PowerShell command prompt:

```bsh
ii .
```

`ii` is a shortcut for `Invoke-Item`.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: Late 2018 on Win7 Pro, "explorer ." results in error message about 64-bit... But "start ." works!

Answer (score 19):

Use the `.` to indicate the current directory:

```
explorer .
```

Answer (score 11):

To add to the answers above  (tested on Windows 10 and 11)

Open current directory

```
explorer .
explorer ...
explorer ....
explorer .......
explorer %cd%

start . 
start ...
start ....
start ........
start %cd%
```

Open the subfolder of the current directory

```
start .\subfolder
explorer .\subfolder
```

Open the parent directory of the current directory

```
explorer ..
start ..
```

Navigate to another folder from the parent directory

```
start ..\another-folder
explorer ..\another-folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file (eg. c:\somepath\q.bat) with this line:

```
explorer .
```

Add it to your path (example shown will only work in the current console, add it to your System Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables to make it work anywhere):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\somepath
```

Then open a command window and type

```
q
```

Then it should open the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

- Press <kbd>CTRL+L</kbd>
- type `cmd`, press enter

Answer (score 0):

just append cmd in the beginning of the address bar in windows.

for eg: if you're at [C:\foo\bar]
just type cmd [cmd C:\foo\bar] and hit enter. this will open a terminal at C:\foo\bar for you.

Comment: The question wasn't about opening a command prompt, but about opening Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

1. Open the desired folder
2. Press <kbd>[CTRL+L]</kbd> or click on the url bar (the current path will be highlited)
3. Type 'cmd' into the url bar and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

[A little img containing the explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUruy.png)